# Calculate measure using [field1] - [field2] > x as filter

Tags: ssas, powerbi, dax

I have a fact table containing columns `OriginalPrice` and `PaidPrice` for customer transactions. I would like to know how many transactions befenit from a discount `OriginalPrice - PaidPrice` between 10 and 20 dollars. I already have a measure `#Customer` that describes the number of customers.

This is for a PowerBI report using a Live connection to SSAS. New columns and some DAX functions are not available in this connection mode.

```
DiscountTier1 = CALCULATE([#Customer],(FactTable[OriginalPrice]-FactTable[PaidPrice]) >= 10, FactTable[OriginalPrice]-FactTable[PaidPrice]) < 20)
```

By doing this I want to know the number of customers that had a discount between 10 and 20 dollars.

Currently I have an error as follows: 
`CALCULATE has been used in a True/False expression that is used as a table filter expression. This is not allowed`

Any suggestions of how to achieve this or what I am doing wrong?
Thank you!

Comment: You can only pass basic filtering as arguments of `CALCULATE` for this sort of thing, you need to use `FILTER`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are searching for a measure like this:

```
DiscountTier1 = 
COUNTROWS(
    FILTER(
        SUMMARIZE (
        'FactTable';
        'FactTable'[customer_id];
        "DISCOUNT"; 
            CALCULATE(SUM(FactTable[OriginalPrice])) - CALCULATE(SUM(FactTable[PaidPrice]))
         );
     [DISCOUNT] <= 20 && [DISCOUNT] >= 10
    ) 
)
```

This query calculates the discount of all rows, and filter the rows with a discount between 10 and 20

Comment: This was super helpful, countrows gave me exactly what I was looking for. Thank you

Answer (score 4):

Add the `FILTER` function as the second parameter of `CALCULATE`, and in this you can  filter the fact table for records satisfying your criteria.  I'd also recommend using the `AND` function for better readability and long term maintenance.

```
DiscountTier1 =
CALCULATE (
    [#Customer],
    FILTER (
        FactTable,
        AND (
            FactTable[OriginalPrice] - FactTable[PaidPrice]
                >= 10,
            FactTable[OriginalPrice] - FactTable[PaidPrice]
                <= 20
        )
    )
)
```